# Javascript - Is there any way to export specific video parts and join them?

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I just want to try a solution for the following problem.

I have a lot of video on my server (in MP4 format).

I want to chose video parts from these videos, and export it.

**For example:**
I have two mp4 videos: `file1.mp4` and `file2.mp4`. Both are 30 minutes long. I want to export a newly created file which contains the first 5 minutes of the first file (`file1.pm4`), and the part between 2:30 and 3:45 of the `file2.mp4`.

> The result should be a downloadable new item: which is 6 minutes and 15 seconds long.

Is there any way to render and download somehow a new video from two other videos?

Comment: javascript ... not easily. your best solution would be to use something like ffmpeg running on your server to create these

Comment: https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do it with JavaScript.

Long answer: At least not without some unstable hacks. JavaScript in webpages is executed in the client computer, and dependent of the environment and the browser user uses. So the recommended & stable way of doing this is implementing your own backed service to render your new video and return the URL. You can use [`Python`](https://www.python.org/) as the programming language, and [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) library for python can handle the API requests to the service. Use a video processing library that matches your needs.

Comment: The question was is there any way? I explained the way. And that is the practical way. I don't understand the down vote from who ever that was.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it in your way.